# Why is $\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}=2^n$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out how many ways you can divide $n$ particles among two halves of a room. This problem is equivalent to having $n$ labeled balls and wanting to know in how many ways you can put them in a box. You can put no ball there. You can also put one ball there and then you have $n!$ of balls to put there, and so on. So, the way I've found to approach this is this

\begin{equation}
N = \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{\displaystyle n!}{\displaystyle (n-r)!r!}
\end{equation}

Where $n$ is the total number of particles and $r$ is how many particles I choose to put in the box every time. I did the calculations for $n=4$ and the result is $16,$ as expected.

The expression above, however, converges to $2^{n}$ and I don't quite understand why. Can you explain to me how this result is obtained without referring back to my original formula? I'm trying to understand if there is a combinatorics reasoning behind it that would make it clearer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For each particle, you have two choices of where to put it.

Comment: So I would imagine the same reasoning would follow if I divided the room in 3 ways? $N=3^2$?

Comment: I think you mean $N=3^n$, but yes, that's exactly the idea.

Comment: Note that the expression doesn't *converge* to $2^n$, it *is* $2^n$.

Comment: If you divided the room in 3 ways you would have the identity
$$
\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n; \,k_i\geq 0}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3}
=(1+1+1)^n
=3^n
$$

Comment: Interestingly, you can see this exact pattern by looking at the entries and the sums of each row in Pascal's triangle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put notice that $ \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{\displaystyle n!}{\displaystyle (n-r)!r!} = \sum_{r=0}^{n}$ $n \choose r$ : (n choose r)

now lets prove  $\sum_{r=0}^{n}$ $n \choose r $ = $2^n$
we want to count the number of ways to devide n people into two groups:

left side: say that in the first group there will be r people, then we need to choose r people from n that will be in the first group the rest will be in the second group : we have $n \choose r$ options for that and we need to sum this option acording to r.

right side: obvious, each person have two options- 1-st group or 2-nd group.